Performance Co-pilot (pcp) necessary? and pmlogger folder filling up
on a Redhat 8.9 system built from rhel-8.9-x86-64.iso as Server with GUI, I have the following rpm's installed (see below) by default I assume.
The folder /var/log/pcp/pmlogger/<hostname>/ has around 200 files that are mostly all compressed to .xz but this folder size is 2 gb.

what is pcp and do I really need it installed?  What function might it be doing that I can't live without?
Is there a way to prevent the pmlogger folder size from growing so large?  Is it ok to remove the contents of this folder?
With the yum remove pcp results show below, is there anything that stands out as being a problem if I go ahead with the removal of pcp?

.
# yum remove pcp

================================================================================
 Package                        Arch   Version             Repository      Size
================================================================================
Removing:
 pcp                            x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream     4.9 M
Removing dependent packages:
 pcp-export-pcp2elasticsearch   x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      22 k
 pcp-export-pcp2graphite        x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      19 k
 pcp-export-pcp2influxdb        x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      22 k
 pcp-export-pcp2json            x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      23 k
 pcp-export-pcp2spark           x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      21 k
 pcp-export-pcp2xml             x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      25 k
 pcp-export-pcp2zabbix          x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      25 k
 pcp-gui                        x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream     2.5 M
 pcp-libs-devel                 x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream     196 k
 pcp-pmda-apache                x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      31 k
 pcp-pmda-bash                  x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      37 k
 pcp-pmda-bcc                   x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream     291 k
 pcp-pmda-bpftrace              x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      66 k
 pcp-pmda-cifs                  x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      57 k
 pcp-pmda-cisco                 x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      79 k
 pcp-pmda-denki                 x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      53 k
 pcp-pmda-dm                    x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream     129 k
 pcp-pmda-elasticsearch         x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      78 k
 pcp-pmda-gfs2                  x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      92 k
 pcp-pmda-gluster               x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      17 k
 pcp-pmda-haproxy               x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      37 k
 pcp-pmda-infiniband            x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      44 k
 pcp-pmda-json                  x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      71 k
 pcp-pmda-libvirt               x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      60 k
 pcp-pmda-lio                   x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      18 k
 pcp-pmda-lmsensors             x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      13 k
 pcp-pmda-logger                x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      42 k
 pcp-pmda-lustrecomm            x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      28 k
 pcp-pmda-mailq                 x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      25 k
 pcp-pmda-mic                   x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      27 k
 pcp-pmda-mongodb               x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      29 k
 pcp-pmda-mounts                x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      25 k
 pcp-pmda-mssql                 x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      80 k
 pcp-pmda-netcheck              x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      66 k
 pcp-pmda-nfsclient             x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      67 k
 pcp-pmda-nvidia-gpu            x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      78 k
 pcp-pmda-openmetrics           x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      76 k
 pcp-pmda-openvswitch           x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      24 k
 pcp-pmda-perfevent             x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream     194 k
 pcp-pmda-podman                x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      92 k
 pcp-pmda-postgresql            x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      75 k
 pcp-pmda-rabbitmq              x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      25 k
 pcp-pmda-roomtemp              x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      37 k
 pcp-pmda-sendmail              x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      49 k
 pcp-pmda-shping                x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      43 k
 pcp-pmda-smart                 x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream     104 k
 pcp-pmda-sockets               x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      73 k
 pcp-pmda-statsd                x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream     173 k
 pcp-pmda-summary               x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      35 k
 pcp-pmda-systemd               x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      33 k
 pcp-pmda-trace                 x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      56 k
 pcp-pmda-unbound               x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      67 k
 pcp-pmda-weblog                x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream     161 k
 pcp-pmda-zswap                 x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      10 k
 pcp-system-tools               x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream     959 k
 pcp-zeroconf                   x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream      14 k
 python3-pcp                    x86_64 5.3.7-18.el8        @AppStream     359 k
Removing unused dependencies:
 HdrHistogram_c                 x86_64 0.9.13-2.el8        @AppStream      45 k
 bcc                            x86_64 0.25.0-5.el8        @AppStream     3.5 M
 bcc-tools                      x86_64 0.25.0-5.el8        @AppStream     1.8 M
 bpftrace                       x86_64 0.16.0-4.el8        @AppStream      11 M
 chan                           x86_64 0.0.4-3.el8         @AppStream      32 k
 clang-libs                     x86_64 16.0.6-2.module+el8.9.0+19521+190d7aba
                                                       @AppStream     108 M
 clang-resource-filesystem      x86_64 16.0.6-2.module+el8.9.0+19521+190d7aba
                                                       @AppStream       0
 compiler-rt                    x86_64 16.0.6-3.module+el8.9.0+20599+53352ad4
                                                       @rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
                                                                       26 M
 gcc-toolset-13-gcc-c++         x86_64 13.1.1-4.3.el8      @AppStream      36 M
 gcc-toolset-13-libstdc++-devel x86_64 13.1.1-4.3.el8      @AppStream      22 M
 libomp                         x86_64 16.0.6-3.module+el8.9.0+19397+8ad4a755
                                                       @AppStream     2.4 M
 libomp-devel                   x86_64 16.0.6-3.module+el8.9.0+19397+8ad4a755
                                                       @AppStream      17 M
 libpfm                         x86_64 4.13.0-4.el8        @AppStream     2.6 M
 libpq                          x86_64 13.11-1.el8         @AppStream     728 k
 lm_sensors                     x86_64 3.4.0-23.20180522git70f7e08.el8
                                                       @anaconda      445 k
 python3-bcc                    x86_64 0.25.0-5.el8        @AppStream     391 k
 python3-jsonpointer            noarch 1.10-11.el8         @AppStream      32 k
 python3-libvirt                x86_64 8.0.0-2.module+el8.9.0+18724+20190c23
                                                       @AppStream     2.0 M
 python3-netaddr                noarch 0.7.19-8.el8        @AppStream     8.4 M
 python3-psycopg2               x86_64 2.7.5-7.el8         @AppStream     544 k
 python3-pyodbc                 x86_64 4.0.30-2.el8        @AppStream     172 k
 unixODBC                       x86_64 2.3.7-1.el8         @AppStream     1.5 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Remove  80 Packages


Removing the gcc toolchain along with openMP, sensor support, ODBC, etc., seems like an extreme solution to regain 2GB of disk space. Have you considered changing the defaults for pmlogger though pmlogger_daily to keep fewer historical files?

I know nothing about pcp nor pmlogger.  After searching and seeing numerous known issues reported about it filling up /var, I found and did systemctl disable pmlogger.service.  In addition to removing some of the older .xz files under the pmlogger folder.

and yum remove --noautoremove  pcp solves the problem of removing the unused dependencies that I don't necessarily want removed with pcp
